# Present as a continued fraction

Tags: continued-fractions

I want represent the fraction  $$\frac{a+b+a b c+a b d}{1+a c+b c+a d+b d+a b c d}\qquad\qquad\qquad (1)$$
as a continued fraction. Here $a,b,c,d$ free variables.

I could only get
$$\frac{a+b+a b c}{1+b c+a d+b d+a b c d}=\frac{1}{d+\frac{1}{a+\frac{1}{c+\frac{1}{b}}}}$$
However, I cannot repersent the original expression (1).

Comment: For the first expression, there's no consistent regular CF for integers $a,b,c$ and $d$.

Comment: Why do you think that it is possible to represent it as a continued fraction?

Comment: – Ng Chung Tak
How could this be proven?

Comment: Using *Mathematica* function “ContinuedFraction” on the 1st expression and varying $a,b,c,d$, the length of the regular CF is **not** fixed and $a,b,c,d$ is **not** necessarily re-appeared on the CF itself.  But the 2nd will do.